# Remove text value onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How to remove input type - value text when user click on it.
How to print Password, not ....... 
Do I must use java script?
Is any way for php to remove dot?

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <form action="testing.php" method="POST">
            <p>SIGN UP</p>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter Name" />
            <input type="password" name="password" value="Enter Password"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: you may use placeholder.. if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Placeholder instead:

```
<input name="Name" placeholder="Enter Name" />
```